# Vim: pressing enter executes unwanted function

Tags: vim

I recently added functions to my `vimrc`, to be able to enter template text when certain keystrokes are pressed. My `vimrc` looks like:

```
set scrolloff=1000

filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.json set ft=javascript

function! Pyf()
    " template for new function in Python
    r~/vim/templates/py_function.py
endfunction
nmap <C-b> :call Pyf()<CR>

function! Pye()
    " template for new exception in Python
    r~/vim/templates/py_exception.py
endfunction
nmap <C-n> :call Pye()<CR>

set colorcolumn=80
```

Ever since the addition of the functions for template insertion, every time I try to edit a file with `Vim`, and press enter, the last function (Pye()) gets executed and fills in text. Without the vimrc changes, pressing enter would just move the cursor to a line below. I would like to stick to this behavior, while keeping the template text insertion only when the specified keystrokes are made. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Change the `nmap` to `noremap`

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose map <CR>`

Comment: @FDinoff, it says: <CR>        * :call Pye()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mapping to `<C-M>` somewhere in your vimrc. `<C-M>` is `<CR>` (the enter key). This is a limitation of how vim handles input.

Comment: @SandeepY you probably want to use a proper template plugin. Also be warned there are other control key combinations that could interact weirdly. For example `<C-I>` is tab and `<C-[>` is escape.

Comment: I tried searching for many but couldn't settle for one that is being actively supported today. My ideal template plugin could, for instance, use a function-name, param-names as input and generate the template of the function. Any suggestions?